# Create multiple new columns for pandas dataframe with apply + function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a pandas dataframe `df` of the following shape: `(763, 65)`

I use the following code to create 4 new columns:

```
df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4']] = df.apply(myFunc, axis=1)

def myFunc(row):
    #code to get some result from another dataframe
    return result1, result2, result3, result4
```

The shape of the dataframe which is returned in `myFunc` is `(1, 4)`. The code runs into the following error:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (763, 4), indices imply (763, 65)

I know that `df` has 65 columns and that the returned data from `myFunc` only has 4 columns. However, I only want to create the 4 new columns (that is, `col1`, `col2`, etc.), so in my opinion the code is correct when it only returns 4 columns in `myFunc`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that fits your situation? Obviously, you do not need to provide 65 columns. 5 columns should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Demo:

```
In [40]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

In [42]: def myFunc(row):
    ...:     #code to get some result from another dataframe
    ...:     # NOTE: trick is to return pd.Series()
    ...:     return pd.Series([1,2,3,4]) * row['a']
    ...:

In [44]: df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3','col4']] = df.apply(myFunc, axis=1)

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
   a  col1  col2  col3  col4
0  1     1     2     3     4
1  2     2     4     6     8
2  3     3     6     9    12
```

**Disclaimer:** try to avoid using `.apply(..., axis=1)` - as it's a `for loop` under the hood - i.e. it's not vectoried and will work *much* slower compared to vectorized Pandas/Numpy ufuncs.

PS if you would provide details of what you are trying to calculate in the `myFunc` functuion, then we could try to find a vectorized solution...

Comment: my problem (of course) was in the hidden code... `myFunc` returned a dataframe with column headings and this lead to the error somehow. I now return as follows and it works: `return result[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']].iloc[0]`. Of course this means that only the first row of the series is taken, which is what I want in my code. As for the vectorization, i will create a new thread later. thx!