# How to group and apply multiple functions?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my `df`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], 
                   'col1': [7,6,12,1,3,6,10,11,12],
                   'col2': [1.2,0.8,0.9,1.1,2.0,1.8,0.7,0.9,1.2]})
```

I want to apply 2 functions, each of which returns strictly 1 output.

```
def myfunc1(g):
    var1 = g['col1'].iloc[0]
    var2 = g.loc[g['col2'] > 1, 'col1'].iloc[0]

    return var1 / var2

def myfunc2(g):
    var1 = g['col1'].iloc[0]
    var2 = g.loc[g['col2'] < 1, 'col1'].iloc[0]

    return var2 - var1
```

If I run them this way, the code fails:

```
df[['new_col1','new_col2']] = df.groupby("id").apply(myfunc1,myfunc2)
```

However, if I run them separately (see below), everything works fine:

```
df['new_col1'] = df.groupby("id").apply(myfunc1)
df['new_col2'] = df.groupby("id").apply(myfunc2)
```

The expected output should have the following columns:

- blade_id
- new_col1
- new_col2

Comment: `myfunc2` throws an error because one of the groups does not have an `iloc[0]` (id 2 does not have a value below 1)

Comment: You could use only one function and return multiple columns, you can refer to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696807/create-multiple-new-columns-for-pandas-dataframe-with-apply-function

Comment: I do not think you are accomplishing what you want to do. Because you groupby "id", the index of the return Series is also "id"; it has values [1, 2, 3].  When you assign a column like you are doing now, it will match based on index of the original dataframe, which is 0-8. So only ROWS 1, 2, 3 will receive a value for your new columns.
Please post the result you expect! and look at @ClemG.'s link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call only one function, so possible solution is create another function:

```
def myfunc1(g):
    var1 = g['col1'].iloc[0]
    #return missing value if no match
    var2 = next(iter(g.loc[g['col2'] > 1, 'col1']), np.nan)

    return var1 / var2

def myfunc2(g):
    var1 = g['col1'].iloc[0]
    #return missing value if no match
    var2 = next(iter(g.loc[g['col2'] < 1, 'col1']), np.nan)

    return var2 - var1
```

---

```
def f(x):
    return pd.Series([myfunc1(x), myfunc2(x)], index=['new_col1','new_col2'])

df1 = df.groupby("id").apply(f)
print (df1)
    new_col1  new_col2
id                    
1   1.000000      -1.0
2   1.000000       NaN
3   0.833333       0.0
```

Or create new function from both:

```
def myfunc3(g):
    var1 = g['col1'].iloc[0]
    var2 = next(iter(g.loc[g['col2'] > 1, 'col1']), np.nan)
    var3 = next(iter(g.loc[g['col2'] < 1, 'col1']), np.nan)

    return  pd.Series([var1 / var2, var3 - var1], index=['new_col1','new_col2'])


df1 = df.groupby("id").apply(myfunc3)
print (df1)
    new_col1  new_col2
id                    
1   1.000000      -1.0
2   1.000000       NaN
3   0.833333       0.0
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot:)